# Issue on Removing Button Outline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap Switch  I have a Checkbox switch at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2GWfJ/1/) and I would like to remove the Blue outline of the element by using this CSS rules:

```
.btn {
    outline: none !important;
}
textarea:hover, input:hover, textarea:active, input:active, textarea:focus, input:focus, button:focus, button:active, button:hover {
    outline:0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

but it is not working. Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: I can not see a blue outline. What browser are you using?

Comment: it is going on Chrome!

Comment: it's not appearing on mine, mac osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/q2zEk/)**

```
.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused {
    border-color: #cccccc;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's part of bootstrap. Hope this helps!

```
.bootstrap-switch:focus{
        outline:none;
    }
```